# How do I reset my password?

Tags: password, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative(root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)

I inherited a machine with Ubuntu desktop installed.  It has a password in place and I have no idea what the password may be.   I cannot get to the command line to use the methods I have found online.  No matter how many times I press "Shift" during the boot process it still goes all the way to the desktop login.  I never see grub.  I am not sure which version I have but I think may be 9 or 10.

Thanks

Doug

---

OK, chapter II

I have 10.04.1, btw.

I tried holding the shift key down and got to the boot menu.  Mine was titled **GNU GRUB 1.98-1unbuntu7**

It has several kernels listed but none say...Ubuntu, KERNEL.  Instead mine says (along with several older versions)

Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-24-generic.

I pressed 'e' on that one anyway and got a page that shows:

recordfail
insmod ext2
set root = '(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set (long id number)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic root=UUID (same long number) ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic

When I try to addd rw init=/bin/bash and hit ESC, then e again it is gone.  If I try to reboot (ctrl-X) after entering the above it goes to the locked desktop.

I also tried the Live CD (I have 8.04.1 on CD).  That worked, up until I tried to mount the existing HD.  It said it was ext4 and was not compatible.  I used the Partition manager and it showed that partition was ext3.  {shrug}

I booted into recovery mode and can get to the root command line.  It shows the machine name but I am not sure where I need to go from there though to find the user info.  Maybe CD /dev/sdb?? I know root is a no-no and I don't want to break it .. . I just want to get in and not have to reinstall!

Thanks

Doug