# How do I reset a lost administrative password?

Tags: password-recovery

I'm working on a Ubuntu system, and my client has completely forgotten his administrative password. He doesn't even remember entering one; however it is there.

I've tried the suggestions on the website, and I have been unsuccessful in deleting the password so that I can download applets required for running some files. Is there a solution?

Comment: In the case where one can't remember ever setting an administrative password, before trying any of the below just type 'password' as the administrative password. It worked for me!

Comment: Related: [How is being able to break into any Linux machine through grub2 secure?](https://askubuntu.com/q/842070/158442)

Comment: Related: [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Comment: In case you also need to reconfigure the console keyboard before you enter your special-character adorned root password: `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` (this actually creates a new initial RAM-disk for the boot process, too) (also, Belgian keyboard layout is _evil_)

Comment: there is also the command `sudo su` to be root in the terminal and you only need a user account and can do all without the root password

Comment: Did you try F12?

Answer (score 951):

By default the first user's account is an administrative account, so if the UI is prompting you for a password it's probably that person's user password. If the  user doesn't remember their password you need to reset it. To do this you need to boot into recovery mode (see also offical docs: [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)).

Boot up the machine, and *after* the BIOS screen, hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (note that for UEFI BIOS you might need press <kbd>ESC</kbd> instead). You will then be prompted by a menu that looks something like this:

[image]

I've noticed on some systems that timing when to hit the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key can be tricky, sometimes I miss it and need to try it again.

Hit the down arrow until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you should see this menu:

[image]

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a root prompt, something like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~#
```

At this stage you should have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now we can set the user's password with the `passwd` command. (In this example I will use jorge as the example, you need to substitute whatever the user's username is):

```
root@ubuntu:~# passwd jorge
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Type in what you want the new password to be at the prompt. After it's successful reboot the machine and the user will be able to log in with their new password.

- [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) documentation
- [Lost password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) documentation

---

There is concern about this being a security vulnerability. ***It is not***. You need to have physical access to the machine to do this. If someone has physical access to your PC, they could do far worse than change a password. When it comes to physical access, the battle for security is lost. Be wary of who you let on your PC.

Even setting a root password will not be successful, as one can simply boot with `init` being `/bin/sh` and have full root access. Again, *given physical access, anyone with computer knowledge can do ANYTHING to your computer.*

Comment: Google needs to learn this.

Comment: I didn't have to remount

Comment: Lenovo Laptop is painful to get to recovery mode. The solution is just after BIOS (i.e. Lenovo logo) press "ESC" holding the left shift key.

Comment: yeah indeed, however in certain circumstances that may be not possible!...To enter either in recovery mode, remount as writer or enter in root shell. Probably because some previously configured systems against hacker attack.

Comment: "select the 2nd entry from the top" - that might not be accurate, in my case 2nd entry was **(upstart)**, not **(recovery mode)**

Comment: _Again, given physical access, anyone with computer knowledge can do ANYTHING to your computer._ is a highly important Linux philosophy.  Physical access usually is stronger than `sudo`.

Comment: If none of these checklists work for you, check out my answer to this issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129559/938717).

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, GRUB `root` required me to enter the root password: https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass

Comment: With modern fast booting computers it's easy to get the timing wrong. 
When holding ESC for too long, you get to the grub prompt _grub>_
From that prompt there is no way to get to the grub menu.
So hitting ESC and letting go a second later was the right timing for me.

Comment: @NonnyMoose Hence why I use DuckDuckGo. 

Comment: this still works on ubuntu v20.10.

Comment: If anyone is concerned about this, encryption is the answer.

Comment: @jewishmoses... What exactly do you mean by `encryption is the answer` -- FDE?

Comment: My Lubuntu prompts were a bit different after the GRUB menu showed. I had more than one Linux version so I just picked the recovery mode of the latest version. I wasn't sure of my user name so after getting into root, I typed `cat /etc/passwd` to get a list of users to verify the user name for the `passwd` command. Holding down the left shift key to get to the GRUB menu worked for me.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to rewrite the keyboard driver using some third party exploit to gain access to this menu remotely?

Answer (score 85):

Yes, you can change the old password via [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB).

1. If you have a single-boot (Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer), to get the boot menu to show, you have to hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during bootup.
2. If you have a dual-boot (Ubuntu is installed next to Windows, another Linux operating system, or Mac OS X; and you choose at boot time which operating system to boot into), the boot menu should appear without the need to hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.
3. From the boot menu, select recovery mode, which is usually the second boot option.
4. After you select recovery mode and wait for all the boot-up processes to finish, you'll be presented with a few options. In this case, you want the *Drop to root shell prompt* option so press the <kbd>ᛎ</kbd> Down arrow to get to that option, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it.
5. Once you're at the root shell prompt, if you have forgotten your username as well, type `ls /home` (small letters & not capitals). This will list all the user accounts in your set up.
6. To reset the password, type `passwd username` where *username* is the username you want to reset, for example, `passwd mysterio` in my case.
7. You'll then be prompted for a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing. Your password is still being accepted. Just type the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're done. You'll be prompted to retype the password. Do so and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
8. Now the password should be reset. Type `exit` to return to the recovery menu.
9. After you get back to the recovery menu, select **resume normal boot**, and use Ubuntu as you normally would — only this time, you actually know the password!

Comment: This offers a route for when you forget both userid *and* password, which would also work with @Jorge Castro's answer.

Comment: The Recovery Menu (step 4 in @Mysterio's list) never came up for me, but I was able to cobble together an alternate solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129559/938717).

Answer (score 64):

If you forgot the password for your Ubuntu system you can recover
using the following steps:

1. Turn your computer on.
2. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> at the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) prompt.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> for edit.
4. Highlight the line that begins `kernel .........` or `linux ........`, press <kbd>e</kbd>
5. Go to the very end of the line and add `rw init=/bin/bash`
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>b</kbd> to boot your system.
   *Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.<sup>1</sup>*
7. Now issue the command `passwd username`
   **where "username" is the user for which you want to change the password.*
8. Then you will be asked to give new password:

   `Enter new UNIX password:`

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-recover-password-under-ubuntu.html)</sup>

Other resources:

- [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)
- [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html)
- [Psychocats](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword/)

For [Xubuntu 14.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu#Xubuntu_14.04_LTS) just follow the screens below. It's similar to some of the other answers.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and choose *Advanced options*

[image]

Choose *recovery mode*:

[image]

Then choose *root*, and once you get the prompt type `passwd <user_name>`, to change the password.

[image]

Comment: The OP may not know what to do at the shell.

Comment: Did not work in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS - no command in GRUB2 beginning kernel or linux.

Comment: @K7AAY see my addition for Xubuntu  14.04.

Comment: you are life saver its worked for me in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: In step 5, worked for me when I also removed "ro" if present, while adding "rw".

Comment: your method always works for me! I would give you +10 if I could.

Comment: Oooooh........ how to take screenshot of Grub man???

Comment: I have done it using a Linux virtual machine with VMware, and screen capture it from the host OS.

Comment: -1, causes a kernel panic

Comment: +1 Used this same technique in `ro` mode to run `fsck -yA` without the administrator password to recover a laptop.

Answer (score 58):

If [Jorge's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/156684) didn't work for you, as it didn't for me, here is another method. I had to try something different because:

1. My USB keyboard did not work at the root prompt ⋯ probably hardware either keyboard or mainboard. To fix I used an old PS/2 keyboard (the little round plug) and use that.
2. When I used `passwd username` to change my password, it failed because of a bad token or such. This called for drastic measures.

### The Drastic Measures

**This is a very dangerous thing to do!** [Jorge's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/156684) should be used; *only* do this in case that method doesn't work.

**Do this at your own risk**. It did work for me on my 11.10 system.

The idea is to set the user's password to blank (or null) - this allows you to just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the `Password:` prompt.

Still at the root prompt from [Jorge's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/156684), first remount the root file system as read-write by using this command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

- Now you are a super-user on this system. *Tread lightly.*

Then edit the password shadow file to remove the encrypted password for your username. Type in:

```
nano -B /etc/shadow
```

The nano editor will display the contents of the file. Each line will have the form `name:⋯:⋯:⋯…` where ⋯ is a string or null (empty). One of the lines will start with your username. The first ⋯ after your username is your encrypted password. As an example:

```
username:$1$amFeNcjp$PprjCKEVk3UtzKwWfEMOY0:14920:0:99999:7:::
```

where `$1$amFeNcjp$PprjCKEVk3UtzKwWfEMOY0` is the encrypted password.

Carefully delete the encrypted password leaving the all the ":"s, so it looks like this:

```
username::14920:0:99999:7:::
```

Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to save, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close **nano**.

Reboot and you will have an empty (or null) password.  Be sure to use `passwd username` in a terminal to set  or reset your user password.

Source for PS/2 workaround was [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector).

Sources for the drastic measures were [here](http://www.debuntu.org/recover-root-password-single-user-mode-and-grub) and [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-change-the-filesystem-from-read-only-to-read-write-185821/).

Note on nano ― the `-B` option makes a backup of the original edited file, same name with a "~" appended.

Comment: You can also use this method by booting with a different disk and editing /etc/shadow after mounting the appropriate disk.

Comment: Or by booting a live CD/USB version. Again this is why physical access to a PC negates all security measures.

Comment: @DaveM *almost* all. Full disk encryption is still not defeated easily. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto fair point. Would it also be possible  using the live CD, chroot into the 'main' system, and perform a password modification ?

Comment: @DaveM as long as you know the FDE password, yes.

Comment: Just stumbled across this very helpful answer.  But...just wondering if a clarification of the above would be good for new users.  In particular, the bold face around the text that says it is a "dangerous thing to do".  It is dangerous because the administrator no longer has a password set; but if you have control of the situation and (for example) are able to physically unplug it from the network before starting, then I don't see it being dangerous any more.  I'm not sure if I missed other reasons why it would be so dangerous.

Answer (score 32):

If recovery mode is disabled, the method I would use is booting to a Live CD or USB. It could be the media you installed from or just another Ubuntu ISO you've downloaded and burnt. The process is *fairly* simple.

1. Boot to the Live media.
2. From the menu, open a terminal.
3. Find out the device name for your primary disk. `sudo fdisk-l` will list all partitions. Derive your partition from the list. We're looking for something like `/dev/sda1` (which it will likely be)
4. Mount this somewhere so we can use it (obviously change the disk to the right one):

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
5. Cross-mount things from the Live install so we can "use" the mounted disk (just copy and paste):

   ```
   for d in dev sys run proc; do sudo mount --bind /$d /mnt/$d; done
   ```
6. Become root on the system by running `sudo chroot /mnt`. You can now do anything root can on the real install.
7. Set the password for the account:

   ```
   passwd username
   ```
8. Reboot and you're done.

Comment: Worked like a champ in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. Recomended.

Comment: If you have a `lvm` partiton, you need to mount it to `/mnt/` first and then mount `dev`  `sys`  `run`  `proc` respectivily.

Answer (score 28):

Ubuntu does not come with an `Administrative` password. There is only one initial account, the user account, which can be used to execute administrative tasks. 
For example, to get a root shell you run

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for myuseraccount:         # here you type the user's password
#
```

A lot of people that have Unix background or experience with other distributions stumble on this issue quite often.

The command

```
su
```

will always fail because the `root` account is locked; it cannot be accessed directly or you cannot login directly to `root`.

There are great advantages in using the `sudo` facility.

Comment: megathanks! I thought that my remote server will always run with current config because I forgot root's password! ))

Comment: thank you.! ^_^

Answer (score 26):

From the official Ubuntu [LostPassword](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) documentation:

1. Reboot your computer
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot to start GRUB menu
3. Highlight your image and press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit
4. Find the line starting with "**linux**" and append `rw init=/bin/bash` at the end of that line
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.
6. Type in `passwd username`
7. Set your password.
8. Type in `reboot`. If that doesn't work, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

This works for Linux Mint 14, too.

Comment: I was working on a computer whose user had lost both the admin and the root passwords. This is the only method that solved his problem, thanks!

Comment: I had to add `mount -rw -o remount /` before step 6, otherwise I get the error "Authentication Token Manipulation Error"

Answer (score 14):

First, you have to reboot into recovery mode.

If you have a single-boot (Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer), to get the boot menu to show, you have to hold down the Shift key during bootup. 
[image]
From the boot menu, select recovery mode, which is usually the second boot option. 
[image]
After you select recovery mode and wait for all the boot-up processes to finish, you'll be presented with a few options. In this case, you want the Drop to root shell prompt option so press the Down arrow to get to that option, and then press Enter to select it.

The root account is the ultimate administrator and can do anything to the Ubuntu installation (including erase it), so please be careful with what commands you enter in the root terminal.

Once you're at the root shell prompt, if you have forgotten your username as well, type

```
ls /home
```

That's a lowercase L, by the way, not a capital i, in ls. You should then see a list of the users on your Ubuntu installation. In this case, I'm going to reset Susan Brownmiller's password.

To reset the password, type

```
passwd username
```

where username is the username you want to reset. In this case, I want to reset Susan's password, so I type

```
passwd susan
```

You'll then be prompted for a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing. Your password is still being accepted. Just type the password and hit Enter when you're done. You'll be prompted to retype the password. Do so and hit Enter again.

Now the password should be reset.

Type `exit`

to return to the recovery menu.

After you get back to the recovery menu, select resume normal boot, and use Ubuntu as you normally would—only this time, you actually know the password!

[source](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

Comment: I get `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error` instead.  Does not want to change it.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to use Jorge's method - the one above with the nice screen shots - with a few minor changes. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

First, when booting up - don't press the left shift key until the BIOS screen goes black and then immediately press and hold the left shift key.

Then, after perhaps a minute and a number of lines of text scroll on the screen, I got the first menu, but with a couple of fewer lines - I chose the second line.

Then I got the Recovery Menu - but when I chose Drop to Root Shell Prompt (bottom item) I was root but couldn't reset the password - because the disks were Read Only.  Type  exit
and get back to the Recovery Menu

There was a choice (not shown on Jorge's screen shot) to Remount Read/Write  Used the down arrow to go to it, then left arrow to get to  and Enter - and it mounted the disk RW.

Then again to Drop to Root Shell Prompt and I'm root and can write - so
passwd username
had me enter the desired password twice - then    exit    to go back to Recovery Menu
Resume normal boot
and everything worked fine with my new password! I'm the only account on this box, and my password works with   sudo   so I apparently have  Administrative Privileges.

This was less exciting than editing   /etc/shadow  but I was glad to trade the excitement for a nice ending.

Comment: For another permutation on Jorge's method, in which no Recovery Menu screen appears, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129559/938717).

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem with my password and I tried everyone's suggestions but none worked for me. So I tried some of my own and this is what worked for me... "Keep in mind I can NOT explain why it worked, all I know is it worked...

**"10 Easy and Simple steps to Reset Lost or Forgotten Password"**

1. Reboot computer and hold the Left Shift Key down.
2. Select boot into recovery mode.

[image]

3. After a few seconds you should get the "Recovery Mode Options" screen.

[image]

**Note:** (Here is the part I can't explain. After trying everything, and nothing working, I finally just started trying all the options here one at a time. When I tried the `"grub Update grub boot loader"` and then followed the rest of the steps all was well and password was reset.)

So before going to the `"root Drop to root shell promt"`selection,

4. Select `"grub Update grub boot loader"`, and you should get this screen.

[image]

5. Select `"Yes"`. Wait for it to go through the update.
6. Now select `"root Drop to root shell prompt"`.
7. Now you should be at a root terminal with something like the following: `youracctname@yourcompname:~$.` type `passwd accountname` ( acountname  being the name of the account you are trying to change the password for ).
8. `Enter new Unix password:` "enter the new password".
9. `Retype new Unix password:` "retype the same password you did in Step-8".
10. It should confirm successful password change. type `exit` at the prompt and reboot.

If this does not work for you, try skipping Steps 4 & 5...

Comment: The GRUB update step might be actually necessary to remount the root partition in read-write mode. If it is indeed the case, a cleaner way would be to `mount / -o remount,rw` before the `passwd` command.

Answer (score 6):

You can change your password if you have access to the file `/etc/shadow` (maybe with your root account, via sudo from another account, from recovery mode, or with a LiveCD/DVD).

This shadow password file has all the users and encrypted passwords (as well as other administrative information) for the system.  The fields are separated by `:` .  For example :

`YOUR_USERNAME:$6$lCu1.iVo$Q3nAL98jBLe5mMJ.0dBDd1Iquz41dDKsP3UdJ4X92gZPwwmQ0vdIEIY8EQxEcYACoMboYhovrpyq7Tm.DztQB.:15520:0:99999:7:::`

The password is the second group of characters after `YOUR_USERNAME`, between the two colons.  You can replace this with a other password, for example, you could replace the existing password string (truncated for clarity):

```
$6$lCu1.iVo$Q3nAL98jBLe5mMJ.0[...]boYhovrpyq7Tm.DztQB.
```

with

`$6$8gMLdPVn$Ych6r5ysKRqhL9jOlg0UPe28KRuzo3TSYMShqb5pzACrE/A0oyDEBFefOgplbboeoe0T9ZqNz7u6Y8YWuQRkz/`

The encrypted string represents "hackme".  This would be your new password.

Comment: Could you add how to generate a new password hash please?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is **no way** to retrieve the old password.

Yes, you can change the password without knowing the old one. The process is described on several sites on the net, easily found via a [search on Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=change+frogotten+password+ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

If you do that however and happened to have used an encrypted `/home` directory for that username you are likely not to gain access to the files in your `/home` directory (and if you do then Ubuntu should be uninstalled...)

Comment: You can *try* to get the old password, actually by cracking it with (e.g. using a program like John, see http://www.openwall.com/john/). However, if the password is not trivial, this might take an extremely long time.

Answer (score 3):

For me, on Ubuntu 16.04 VM installed in VirtualBox, when I boot into (with <kbd>shift</kbd> held before booting the VM) the root prompt, I always get `Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue)`, finally I hit `e` at the GRUB menu with the newest recovery kernel selected in **Advanced Options for Ubuntu**

[image: Advanced Options for Ubuntu in GRUB menu (kernels list)]

and the hit `Down` scroll to the bottom, and see a line

```
linux /boot/...  ro recovery nomodeset
```

I scrolled to this line with Down/Up arrows, and moved to the end of this line of end, and changed `ro recovery nomodeset` to `rw init=/bin/bash`, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

This will boot you into the system as root, and you can change your password as normal.

[image: GRUB editor screen with arrows to parameters]

Comment: How does this answer the question about resetting a password? `nomodeset` is not related at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't know  `nomodeset` at all, but I when I try  replace these  things with `rw init=/bin/bash`, then it works, that's all.

Comment: `nomodeset` is not set by default. You must have added that parameter at some point. In any case, whether you remove it or not, setting `init=/bin/bash` will cause the system to boot into a Bash shell as described. Note that you can `exec /sbin/init` from there to complete a normal boot :)

Comment: Zanna,  Thanks for the explanation, but It did set by default in the recovery mode

Comment: @Pilot6, @Zanna, the `nomodeset` actually is the setting on some systems. My Dell refurb with Ubuntu 18.04 came with `ro recovery nomodeset` and updating the password requires changing it as @fangxing describes. [This](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en) may explain why. Also, that value will automatically revert to `ro recovery nomodeset` on reboot. It just needs to be manually changed for this process.

Answer (score 2):

In the boot GRUB menu, you may append `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel boot parameter to get a root shell.

Comment: It is the password of Ubuntu my friend .And I got it done .Any way a big thanks to you too for your kindness Xie.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

## **PROCEED only if all the following step are familiar and know what happens in each step.**

1. Boot using live USB
2. `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`
3. `sudo nano -B /mnt/etc/shadow`
4. remove the encrypted pwd following the user who's password you want to set it to
5. Save the file and quit nano
6. Reboot from HDD
7. login with the user who's password was set to
8. `passwd <user who's password was set to empty>`

Go to beach!

Comment: I didn't have a live USB and the above didn't work for me, but for Ubuntu 18.04 [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129559/938717) ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

**Password Recovery**

Step 1: Go to Safe mode by holding Shift or pressing Escape key while booting
[image]
Step 2: Press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit command
Step 3: Search for "linux" and change **ro** to **rw** (It should be at bottom)
[image]
Step 4: Add `init=/bin/sh` at end of current line
[image]
Step 5: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to Reboot

You might need to remove  `splash $vt_handoff` if present.

Now you should get a CLI shell

type `nano /etc/shadow`
[image]
remove all value from `$` to `:` of the account you want to access.
 
[image]
[image]
Save the file and then reboot.

You should be able Log in without password.

P.S.
I have tried it on Ubuntu 16.04, not sure if it works on 18.04
**Note: This has nothing to do with your BIOS, we are tweaking the GRUB**
Good Luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95212/discussion-on-answer-by-white-mars-how-to-get-into-the-bios).